# How do you search all mail using edeR/gmail?

Tags: r, gmail, imap

What is the folder argument to select all mail using the `edeR` imap package?

```
require(edeR)
x <- extractMbox(username="<redacted>@gmail.com", password="<redacted>",folder="???",nmail=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- extractMbox(username="<redacted>@gmail.com", password="<redacted>",folder="[Gmail]/All Mail",nmail=2)
```

Comment: Is this advertising? It looks pretty much like what you see in `?extractMbox`

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments. This is standard SO answering your own question. I couldn't find the question on SO, did some research on my own, found the answer, and posted it for the benefit of others. I'm not involved in the development of this package.

Comment: nowhere in the help page does it show how to search all mail. The tag "All Mail" isn't necessarily intuitive because the gmail search syntax is "in:all"

Comment: Agreed it's not intuitive, but is pretty easy to find. I found "All Mail" expression in the first Google hit to a search on "gmail folders": https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10708?hl=en